# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression? Looping through an array to return items based on layoutType

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm wanting to display images in different spots based on their layoutType.

I'm new to SwiftUI so please bare with me, I've got a solution that in my mind makes sense however I'm getting this error. `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

I've done my fair share of Googling the error and it appears that it came be produced from many different issues. The error appears on `var: body some View`

I'll start by showing you my struct:

```
struct Mod: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var images: [String]
    var layoutType: Int
    
}
```

Then my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var mods: [Mod] = [
        Mod(images: ["image1", "image2"], layoutType: 1),
        Mod(images: ["image3"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image4"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image5"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image6"], layoutType: 2)
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(mods) { mod in
                        if mod.layoutType == 1 {
                            ForEach(mod.images, id: \.self) { item in
                                VStack {
                                    Image(item)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a kind of a typo, replace `ForEach(mods.count)` with `ForEach(mods)`

Comment: @vadian I had this the first time around with the same error, changing it to `mods.count` in hopes that was the issue. Just changed it back though, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the typo `mod.count` you have indeed to split the view into subviews. Extract the inner `ForEach`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var mods: [Mod] = [
        Mod(images: ["image1", "image2"], layoutType: 1),
        Mod(images: ["image3"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image4"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image5"], layoutType: 2),
        Mod(images: ["image6"], layoutType: 2)
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(mods) { mod in
                        if mod.layoutType == 1 {
                            SubView(mod: mod)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    let mod : Mod
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(mod.images, id: \.self) { item in
            VStack {
                Image(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```